# VBA Textbox value loop vlookup for number of times value is found

Tags: vba, excel

I am creating a table in my spreadsheet that contains categories, questions and answers for a quiz.
The user is presented with a form, allowing them to navigate around the workbook easily, this also includes a textbox option, allowing them to search for a phrase if they are unsure what category the question/answer may fall into.

I have generated a vlook up to pull from the table of categories/questions and answers to the user on a different worksheet.
I have also generated a count, so I am able to identify how many times this work appears across the quiz table.

My problem is I am struggling to develop a loop so that if the key phrase is found 6 times for example, i want 6 questions and answers to be listed to the user. Currently it is only pulling the final time it is found.

My current code includes the following:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    If Len(search_text) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Please enter a key word to search for!", vbCritical
    End If

    Dim wordCount As Integer
    wordCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheet1.Range("A2:c600"), "*" & search_text.Value & "*")
    'Else: wordCount = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheet1.Range("A2:c600"), search_text.Value)

    If wordCount = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No match found"
    Else
        Sheet2.Range("a7").Value = WorksheetFunction.VLookup("*" & search_text.Value & "*", Sheet1.Range("A2:c600"), 3, False)
        Sheet2.Range("b7") = wordCount
    End If

End Sub
```

Any advice on implementing a loop and to allow the question/answer to be printed one after another would be very much appreciated.
I have read many other question pages about this and none seem to match what I am trying to do.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want to search the category, questions, and answers for the phrase the user enters?  VLOOKUP only looks at the left-most column, so it is not looking up in 2 of your 3 columns, additionally VLOOKUP only returns one result.

Comment: yes i would like it to search all columns. could you advise what would be best formula/function to do this in that case? many thanks

Comment: Okay, I am going to tinker with some code using the `Find` method.  This is equivalent to opening the "Find" dialog box by pressing CTRL+F and looking that way.  [This](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/find-method.htm) is a good starting point and I will see what I can come up with myself.

Answer (score 1):

I use a combination of `Find` and `FindNext` to search through a range of cells for the term entered in the `search_text` input field.  I added comments to my code to better help you understand what exactly is going on.

I don't know exactly what you need to do with the results when you find them, for now I just display a message box showing the match.  We can work on what to actually do with the results if you want to clarify in the comments what exactly you want.

This code assumes you have a worksheet named `Results`

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

        Dim rngResult As Range
        Dim strFirstAddress As String
        Dim i As Long

        If Len(search_text.Text) = 0 Then
                MsgBox "Please enter a key word to search for!", _
                        vbCritical

                'Stop code exeuction if no search
                'term is entered
                Exit Sub
        End If

        'Clear the previous results range
        Sheets("Results").Range("A2:C600").ClearContents

        'Set i to row 2 of the results worksheet
        i = 2

        'Look in range A2:C600 of Sheet1
        With Sheet1.Range("A2:C600")

                'Perform the initial find
                Set rngResult = .Find(What:=search_text.Text, LookAt:=xlPart)
                        'Check to ensure that the term is found
                If Not rngResult Is Nothing Then
                        'Grab the cell address of the first match
                        'This will help to avoid an infinite loop
                        strFirstAddress = rngResult.Address
                        'Continue Searching
                        Do

                                'Display the output to you
                                'MsgBox "Matched '" & search_text.Text & "' to " & rngResult.Value & " in cell " & rngResult.Address

                                'Put the result on the results page
                                Sheets("Results").Range("A" & i & ":C" & i).Value = Range("A" & rngResult.Row & ":C" & rngResult.Row).Value
                                i = i + 1

                                'Move on to the next result
                                Set rngResult = .FindNext(rngResult)

                        'Break out of the loop when we return to the starting point of the search
                        Loop While Not rngResult Is Nothing And rngResult.Address <> strFirstAddress
                End If
        End With

        'Clean up variables
        Set rngResult = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Once is has found the result I would like it to display in a different worksheet the results found - almost copying the sections from the original table. so display the category, the question and the answer that matches the word found, so the user can then see all the relevant information. I suppose in some cases just like doing a search on the internet and the results being tailored around that search. hope that makes it clearer what i would like the found answers to be displayed as. thank you for your help so far

Comment: Alright I have updated my code to send whatever the code finds to a worksheet named Results.  Hopefully this works for you!

Comment: When I ran this code, the results page shows:  #N/A
 
 
Results: 
Results: 
Results: Any thoughts. many thanks

Comment: What did you enter into the search box?

Comment: text that is displayed in the sheet/area the code is looking into. so it should find a match no problem. in the previous code this worked fine displaying in message box answers found. in a nut shell id like it to print the entire row of the table that the word is found in. hope that helps?

Comment: any ideas on this matter?

Comment: Is there any way you could post 3-5 lines of columns A-C in Sheet1?  I may not be understanding how the data is formatted.  I use a tool like [this](http://www.tablesgenerator.com/text_tables) just be sure to copy + paste in and format the data as code and it should show as a table.